# bad generators of keys in a particular bst style

Tags: bibtex, formatting, pdftex

I have the following the `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]

\usepackage{jucs2e} \usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

cite~\cite{EnviroTrack}

\bibliographystyle{jucs}  \bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

When I created the `.bbl` file with Bibtex, I get:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1} \newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''} \providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}

\bibitem[{Blum et~al.(2004)Blum, Cao, Chen, Evans, George, George, Gu, He,   Krishnamurthy, Luo, Son, Stankovic, Stoleru and Wood}]{EnviroTrack} Blum, T. A.~B., Cao, Q., Chen, Y., Evans, D., George, J., George, S., Gu, L.,   He, T., Krishnamurthy, S., Luo, L., Son, H., Stankovic, J., Stoleru, R.,   Wood, A.: \enquote{Envirotrack: Towards an environmental computing paradigm   for distributed sensor networks}; Proceedings of the 24th International   Conference on Distributed Computing System; 582--589; 2004.

\end{thebibliography}
```

The generated bibitem key/identifier is wrong because this bibitem adds names of year "Blum, Cao, Chen, Evans, George, George, Gu, He, Krishnamurthy, Luo, Son, Stankovic, Stoleru and Wood". I think the behavior is due to the *jucs* style I am using.

Can anybody help me? Is it necessary to attach *jucs* style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be some confusion about the purpose and structure of the Main and optional arguments of the `\bibitem` macro.

- The *main argument* of `\bibitem` (the material in curly braces) -- here: `EnviroTrack` -- is the "key", i.e., what one writes as the argument of a `\cite` (or `\citet`, `\citet*`, etc) command.
- The *optional argument* of `\bibitem` -- the material in square brackets -- determines what the citation call-out looks like. It would seem that you (or the package `jucs2e`) loaded the citation management package `natbib`. With `natbib` loaded, the instruction `\cite{EnviroTrack}` will produce the truncated callout `Blum et al. (2004)`.

  In contrast, with the instruction `\citet*{EnviroTrack}` LaTeX will produce an unabridged callout (with all authors' names listed):

  ```
  Blum, Cao, Chen, Evans, George, George, Gu, He, Krishnamurthy, Luo,
  Son, Stankovic, Stoleru and Wood (2004)
  ```

In short, as long as `natbib` is loaded -- which seems to be the case for your document -- the material in square brackets appears to be correct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\citet{EnviroTrack}

\citet*{EnviroTrack}

\begin{thebibliography}{1} 
\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''} 
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\bibitem[{Blum et~al.(2004)Blum, Cao, Chen, Evans, George, George, Gu, He, 
Krishnamurthy, Luo, Son, Stankovic, Stoleru and Wood}]{EnviroTrack} Blum, T. A.~B., 
Cao, Q., Chen, Y., Evans, D., George, J., George, S., Gu, L., He, T., Krishnamurthy, 
S., Luo, L., Son, H., Stankovic, J., Stoleru, R., Wood, A.: \enquote{Envirotrack: 
Towards an environmental computing paradigm for distributed sensor networks}; 
Proceedings of the 24th International Conference on Distributed Computing System; 
582--589; 2004.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```